# change url and formData in jQuery File Upload Plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-file-upload

```
    // Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin.
    jQuery( '#upload' ).fileupload
    ({

        url: ajaxurl,
        formData: { data: FormData },

   });
```

I tried this but plugin not uploading the files. is this the right way to add url and formData?

using above values in ajax works:

```
jQuery.ajax
({
    url: ajaxurl,
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    xhr: function()
});
```

However, I need to use that plugin.

Comment: did you select the files to upload ?

Comment: yes i have them in the formData.

Comment: I mean, when you `click` the `#upload` element from the browser you will be prompt to pick the files to upload. And `autoUpload` must be set `true` but which is `true` by default. Did you perform that ?

Comment: yeah it shows the upload files with their progress bars on the front end but don't upload the files. and this is because its not getting the url and formData values.

Comment: wrap you code with `$(function(){/*Code goes Here */})();`. And make sure that `ajaxurl` and `FormData` are defined before initializing the uploader. And view the console, if there is any network error (404s) or something.

Comment: no network error happened but files didn't got uploaded. i think url option is not setting right

Comment: I noticed one thing , but may not be the actual problem. Try removing extra comma char from your options `formData: { data: FormData },` and please let me know what happened.

Comment: yeah same problem. nothing happened.